# How to submit Decimal to Django API?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, decimal

I've got a model with a `DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=20)`, but when I pass a string value of `'1.10'` to the relevant API endpoint it gets saved to the Postgres database as 1.10000000000000000000. How do I ensure that it gets saved as 1.10?

Answer (score -1):

Your `DecimalField` says there should be 20 digits. Logically it adds twenty decimal places and stored in DB  but you can display your data using `normalize` filter in your templates. such as

```
{{my_decimal_field.normalize}}
```

it will remove unnecessary 0's from your template. I hope it will help.

Comment: `decimal_places` is not optional, so I can't avoid specifying it. `normalize` removes trailing zeros, which is information I really do want in the output (number of significant digits). Logically, if not mathematically, decimal 1.10 is distinct from both 1.1 and 1.100000, because the number of significant digits determines how the number should be shown and interpreted.